# Angular 2 currency pipe format

Tags: angular, pipe, currency, angular2-pipe

Now i have:
`<span>{{(price | currency: 'EUR': true)}}</span>`

and this outputs with standard format **1,000.00**

but i need this format **1.000,00**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AppModule class change locale.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     //
  ],
  imports: [
    //
  ],
  providers: [
    //
  { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "de-DE" }

],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }`
```

de-DE is just an example, use whatever locale u want.

More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Using_locales